# Use powerpoint object-model without running the powerpoint application

Tags: vba, com, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint

I need to create a server which allows multiple users to connect, upload their Powerpoint presentations and get modified presentations back. The presentations should be processed simultaneously (using threads). Powerpoint is installed on the server.

Is there a way to use the powerpoint object-model without running the full powerpoint application?
(I already know I can use OpenXML, but I'm asking about the object model.)

Anybody knows if presentations could indeed be processed simultaneously (perhaps in different windows or instances)?

Comment: If PPT is installed on a server, and only the server requires PPT, then why would the lack of the PPT application on the client machines be an issue? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has to be an instance of PowerPoint to automate before you can automate an instance of PowerPoint.

You can't access its object model without running it.

PowerPoint only allows one instance of itself, so multiple simultaneous instances isn't possible, at least on a per user login basis ... you might be able to make it fly by running multiple instances inside multiple login sessions.  Mutltiple VMs running a copy each of PPT might be another possibility.

While you can open multiple presentations inside a single instance of PPT, it would be counterproductive.  It wouldn't make the processing happen any more quickly; would probably slow things down because multiple open presentations would consume more resources.

In my experience, your best bet is to serialize the process so that you open and process one file at a time.  Since you mention multiple windows, let me toss this in:  if at all possible, don't open any presentations in a window; in most cases it's not necessary, and keeping the presentation hidden will speed things up considerably.

Comment: Note that even if you get this to work that it is not supported to do office automation on a server for a whole bunch of reasons. To quote: "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment." (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us)

Comment: That document then goes on to describe the various problems you're liable to run into if you try to automate server-side.  Some of these don't apply to PowerPoint, where you don't have to deal with problems arising from multiple instances.  The other problems can be solved, at least for some applications.  Another approach, one I rather prefer, is to give an independent PC access to a shared folder on the server (where uploaded files appear) and let the independent PC do the processing.  That way any glitches won't tie up or otherwise affect the server.